# Flashing firmware Google Enterprise Edition 2

Tags: google-glass, firmware, flashing

My GEE2 is currently running on version OPM1.190831.007, and I can't find a way to get a more recent version running. I've tried the flashing tool and manual flashing, but both methods came with their own issues. I'll give them below:

Flashing tool: I get either a 'device already in use' connection error or the device is offline. This besides the more common message that the flashing tool has some problems on windows sometimes, and that I should try refreshing the webpage.

Manual flashing: once I have given the adb reboot-bootloader command, the fastboot devices command won't recognize the device (listed as ???????? instead of the device name/number) or it will be offline. As a result, the commands that should be given afterwards according to the Readme file don't work.

I have the adb debugger from the Android Studio SDK platform-tools folder, so I updated the driver software of the GEE2 with the use of that folder initially. Afterwards I tried installing other adb software as well but that didn't help either.

I have also tried a couple of the simpler solutions, as unplugging and plugging, refreshing the site, using another computer, using another internet browser, deinstallation of the driver software, a factory reset of the GEE2, installing less recent firmware instead of the latest. None of these things changed the outcome.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I had similar issue while using windows. Try it on Linux or Mac. Same steps will work. I think Windows android adb drivers are conflicting with other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check if you have enabled developer options on EE2.

I had a hard time flashing it on Windows due to driver issues. My Android studio or ADB had no problem deploying apps to EE2, but the fastboot never worked. I ended up flashing it on a Mac using brew installed adb.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with Windows, the driver, and fastboot not working using the flash tool. I was told by support to use a USB 2.0 port. I used a Mac with USB 2.0 to flash it and it was successful.

Answer (score 0):

There's a flaw with the instructions on google glass firmware update - for Windows only, there's a USB driver you need that is glass-specific which isn't mentioned anywhere on the page. I can't even find the page where I found that out right now and I know what I'm looking for. Which isn't very helpful.

The best I can give you is a link to [this installer tool](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-latest-adb-fastboot-and-usb-driver-installer-tool-for-windows.3999445/) might sort out your problem judging [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/googleglass/comments/fq9hrc/glass_enterprise_2_driver/).

If that doesn't work, use a mac or linux.